# The relation A defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $ \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} , xAy \iff x - y = 2k$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

The relation A defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $ xAy \iff  \exists k \in \mathbb{Z},  ~x - y = 2k$ is an equivalence relation.

Proof. We must show that xAy is reflexive, symmetry and transitive.

Since A is a relation on $\mathbb{R}$, so that $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then xAx
is relation iff $x-x = 2k$. Hence A is reflexive Since k = 0 and $k \in
\mathbb{Z}$.

Since xAy iff $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, x - y = 2k$, then we have yAx iff
$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, y-x =2k$. If there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, such
that $x - y = 2k$, then there must exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $y-x =
2k$. Hence A is symmerty.

Let $a \in R$, we have yAa as $y - a = 2k$, also we have xAy as $x - y = 2k$. We
take the union, then we have $(xAy) \cup (yAa) ~iff~ \exists k \in \mathbb{Z},
(x-y+y-a) = 2k.$ Therefore, xAa iff $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, x -a = 2k$. Hence
A is transitive.

Since A is reflexive, symmetry and transitive. Hence A is an equivalence
relation on $\mathbb{R}$. $\blacksquare$

Does my proof correct? Do I need to worried about the domain of relation is $\mathbb{R}$ while we want to show the existence is on $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: This equivalence relation defines a circle of circumference 2.

Comment: @dejongbrent what is the circle of circumference?

Comment: Every circle has a circumference. The circumference of this one is 2.

Comment: As for your proof, I think it's pretty much right, but you should be more explicit about the values of each k you show to exist.

Comment: @dejongbrent ok, I am just confused that in the prove of transitive step how to prove x - a in Z. Also how does the circle of circumference related to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to worried about the domain of relation is $\Bbb R$ while we want to show the existence is on $\Bbb Z$.

No.   It is of no concern.

Any ordered pair of *real numbers* will be A-related if their difference is an *even integer*.  $$\forall (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: \quad (x,y)\in A \iff [\exists k\in \Bbb Z: 2k=x-y]$$

$2.314$ and $12.314$ are real numbers whose difference is an even integer, $10$, so they are A-related.

$2$ and $\pi$ are real numbers whose difference is *not* an even integer, so they are *not* A-related.

---

> Does my proof correct?

It... needs polishing, but you have the right approach.   Here one way I'd write it.

- Reflexive:   Because $0$ is an even integer, then any real number is A-related to itself.
- Symmetric:   Because the negative of an even integer is also an even integer, then if any ordered pair of real numbers are A-related, then the reverse-ordered pair is also A-related. vis: $$x-y=2k ~\to~ y-x=2(-k)$$
- Transitive:   Because the sum of two even integers is also an even integer, then if any two ordered pairs of real numbers of the form $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ are both A-related, then so too is $(x,z)$. vis: $$[~x-y=2k_1~\wedge~ y-z=2k_2~]~\to~ x-z=2(k_1+k_2)$$

It covers the points you were trying to raise in clear natural language, with symbols to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I have one similar question, the relation S in on R, and xSy iff there exists q in Q such that x = yc^q. When I prove for the transitive, I let m in R, and have xSy and ySm,so that x = (mc^q) * (c^q)  then I got x = mc^2q. Then S is transitive, since there is a q such that x = mc^q.  Is this approach correct?

Comment: @bagman If you mean, $\exists q_1\in\Bbb Q\, \exists q_2\in\Bbb Q~((x=yc^{q_1}\wedge y=mc^{q_2})~\to~x=mc^{q_1+q_2})$ then yes.  $$\therefore ~~((\exists q\in\Bbb Q~x=yc^q)\wedge( \exists q\in\Bbb Q~y=mc^q))~\to~(\exists q\in\Bbb Q~x=mc^q)$$

Comment: Yes, so this approach is that we assume xSy and ySm, then we use it to show xSm, that is $x = mc^q$ (in this case $x = mc^{q_1 + q_2}$) by substitute $y = mc^{q_2}$ into $x = yc^{q_1}$. Does it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'll prove the statement, following your proof as closely as I comfortably can while still maintaining proper English.

Proof. We show that $A$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

For any $x$, $x-x=0=2\cdot 0$, hence $xAx$ and $A$ is reflexive.

Suppose $xAy$. Then $x-y=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $y-x=2(-k)$, and $-k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $yAx$. Hence $A$ is symmetric.

Suppose we have $xAy$ and $yAa$. Then $x-y=2k_1$ and $y-a=2k_2$ for some $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $x-a=(x-y)+(y-a)=2k_1+2k_2=2(k_1+k_2)$, and $k_1+k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $xAa$; hence $A$ is transitive.

Since $A$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, $A$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$. ■

Comment: That is a great proof. Thanks!